# How to enable read write amazon s3 bucket permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, ghost-blog

I want to connect my [ghost blog](https://github.com/cobyism/ghost-on-heroku) made with heroku to my s3 bucket in aws to be able to upload images in posts.

I have my user ARN: arn:aws:iam::916616152568:user/*myuser* attached to a group with "AmazonS3FullAccess".

What am I doing wrong?

Public access settings for this bucket:

```
Manage public access control lists (ACLs)
Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects (Recommended)
True

Remove public access granted through public ACLs (Recommended)
True
Manage public bucket policies

Block new public bucket policies (Recommended)
False

Block public and cross-account access if bucket has public policies 
(Recommended)
False
```

And my bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::916616152568:user/*myuser*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*myS3bucket*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::916616152568:user/*myuser*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*Object",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*myS3bucket*/*"
    }
]
}
```

I have already uploaded the `S3_ACCESS_BUCKET_NAME` , `S3_ACCESS_BUCKET_REGION`, `S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `S3_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY` to my heroku environment variables

I'm having this error uploading the files from my ghost server. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)` But no problem if I login and upload from the aws console.

Comment: What about your IAM policy? Have you attached a policy giving access to bucket?

Comment: The one there, or you mean some other policy?

Comment: see my answer. You'll need to create an IAM policy

Comment: That's exactly the same code that I have up there. I have it linked to my bucket.

Comment: Have you linked the policy to your IAM user though? Bucket policy and IAM policies are different.

Comment: In IAM, I have a group with AmazonS3FullAccess policy. Linked to the " arn:aws:iam::916616152568:user/*myuser* ". Then in my bucket policy I have whats up there.

Comment: When you log in with this user are you able to download and upload files to this bucket?

Comment: Yes, I can upload/download

Comment: Then it isn't a permission issue. Please update question with what error you are getting

Comment: I have this error. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden).

Comment: This might be a CORS issue. Can you try this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed it by changing all the "Public access settings for the bucket" to false.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an IAM policy to allow your IAM user access to bucket. Create a policy similar to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_rw-bucket.html) from IAM. Then go to your user and attach the same policy to him.